# Ignore redefined attribute xml

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an xml file sometimes an element contains a multiplied attribute (not an ID) and he has the same value, something like this :

```
<names>
   <name attribute="abc"  attribute="abc" />
</names>
```

I know this is a false writing, so I want to ignore the error  when I read the file in Php with this code :

```
 $xmlDoc->load( 'file.xml' );
```

It's possible ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Pass some options while loading:

```
$xmlDoc->load('file.xml', LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
```

And the standard http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php